# Videojs plugins with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video.js

How do I use [Videojs plugins](https://videojs.com/plugins/) in angular 4 project? Many plugins don't have typeScript declaration files(*.d.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by extending the `video.js` module like so:

```
declare module 'video.js' {
    interface Player {
        // your plugin function definitions here
        // for example:
        offset(offset?: { start?: number, end?: number, restart_beginning?: boolean }): void;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do this with the rangeslider-videojs plugin - https://github.com/acpmasquerade/rangeslider-videojs/

Answer (score 0):

types are avaible for video.js so you can actually download it and use very easy

using npm: npm i -D @types/video.js

using yarn: yarn add -D @types/video.js

Hope that helps you can check the official info here
[npmjs info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/videojs)