# video.js Version 8.X.X Types, TypeScript React and Plugins [2023]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plugins, video.js

### The Issue:

**Background**: I am porting a jQuery app with video.js with plugins. to TypeScript React app.

Trying to use video.js current version of 8.3.0 with TypeScript and 3rd-party plug-ins causes type errors such as: `Property 'playlist' does not exist on type 'Player'`.

### Simplified Example

It should be noted, this setup actually works in production with multiple plugins, however TS server throws errors.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import type Player from 'video.js/dist/types/player';
import 'videojs-playlist';

const videoElement = document.createElement('video-js');
const playerRef = useRef<Player | null>(null);
const playlist = [{...}];
const options = {...};

const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options));

player.autoplay(false);
player.playlist(playlist); // TS Error: Property 'playlist' does not exist on type 'Player'
player.playlist.autoadvance(0); // TS Error: Property 'playlist' does not exist on type 'Player'
```

### Previous Research, Attempts at Resolution and Potential Cause

This is actually a common issue for folks wanting to use video.js with TypeScript and 3rd-party plug-ins. While there viable solutions for this scenario using video.js version 7.X, none of the following solutions work for me on video.js 8.3.

I believe this happened when they changed how their types work.

Initially, we used DefinitelyTyped types for 7.X:

```js
npm install --save @types/video.js
```

Then we used the included types in 7.X:

```js
import { VideoJsPlayer, VideoJsPlayerOptions } from 'video.js';
```

In the 8.X release they changed their types:

```js
import Player from 'video.js/dist/types/player';
```

I found previous success in another app that uses video.js 7.X with these solutions, however neither of these solutions work for me on 8.3:

- [Video.js Heart TypeScript](https://joeflateau.net/posts/video-js-heart-typescript)
- [StackOverflow - Videojs plugins with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683503/videojs-plugins-with-typescript)

I took at look at the `video.js` player.d.ts file for clues, however I wasn't able to figure it out from there.

I also have tried this custom d.ts file example, even throwing in some `any`s just to get it up and running, but no luck:

```js
// videojs-playlist.d.ts
import Player from 'video.js/dist/types/player';

declare module 'video.js' {
  export interface Player {
    playlist(options: any): void; // Also tried playlist(playlist?: { options: any }): void;
  }
}
```

I asked co-pilot and it gave me a bunch of depreciated, not functional code, not compatible with video.js version 8.X.

Falling back to 7.X is not a real option for this project.

Again, functionality works, however TS server continues to complain. I suspect the solution is ultimately in a `custom.d.ts` file. Hopefully someone has been able to figure this out for the version 8.X of video.js. Thank you in advance.